# NSString to Print in in binary format

Tags: objective-c

I dont understand of the below case of converting int to byte , the below java code can able to print the byte value as below

System.out.println("binary output   ::: "+Byte.toString(bo[0]));
            System.out.println("binary   output   ::: "+Byte.valueOf(bo[1]));
            System.out.println("binary output   ::: "+Byte.valueOf(bo[2]));
            System.out.println("binary   output   ::: "+Byte.valueOf(bo[3]));
            System.out.println("binary output   ::: "+new String(bo));

binary output   ::: 0
binary output   ::: 0
binary output   ::: 0
binary output   ::: 1
binary output   ::: squaresquaresquaresquare ( 4 square chars) - binary data

but when i make a objective-c code to the same data into final NSString it also prints as "0001" but not in binary format ( 4 square chars)

I need NSString in binary format how do i print NSString in binary format instead of "0001"

please help

Comment: obj-c code is
uint8 barr[4];
barr[0] =(uint8)num;  
barr[1] =(uint8)num>>8;  
barr[2] =(uint8)num>>16;  
barr[3] =(uint8)num>>24;  
i am using [NSString stringwithFormat:@%i,barr[i]]

which %? i need to use to get the byte value(binary data) as it is from the array?

Answer (score 5):

If readability is an issue, let me suggest a quick routine which will turn an int into a string of nibble-sized groupings of "1" and "0" characters:

```
NSString *binaryRepresentation(int value)
{
    long nibbleCount = sizeof(value) * 2;
    NSMutableString *bitString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:nibbleCount * 5];

    for (int index = 4 * nibbleCount - 1; index >= 0; index--)
    {
        [bitString appendFormat:@"%i", value & (1 << index) ? 1 : 0];
        if (index % 4 == 0)
        {
            [bitString appendString:@" "];
        }
    }

    return bitString;
}
```

So that
`binaryRepresentation(1)` returns `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001`

and

`binaryRepresentation(1423)` returns `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101 1000 1111`

Answer (score 4):

you could use this function

```
+ (NSString *)getBitStringForInt:(int)value {

    NSString *bits = @"";

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i ++) {
        bits = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%@", value & (1 << i) ? 1 : 0, bits];
    }

    return bits;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
@interface NSString (BinaryStringRepresentation)

+ (NSString *)binaryStringRepresentationOfInt:(long)value;
+ (NSString *)binaryStringRepresentationOfInt:(long)value numberOfDigits:(unsigned int)length chunkLength:(unsigned int)chunkLength;

@end

@implementation NSString (BinaryStringRepresentation)

+ (NSString *)binaryStringRepresentationOfInt:(long)value
{
    const unsigned int chunkLength = 4;
    unsigned int numberOfDigits = 8;
    return [self binaryStringRepresentationOfInt:value numberOfDigits:numberOfDigits chunkLength:4];
}

+ (NSString *)binaryStringRepresentationOfInt:(long)value numberOfDigits:(unsigned int)length chunkLength:(unsigned int)chunkLength
{
    NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString new];

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
        NSString *divider = i % chunkLength == chunkLength-1 ? @" " : @"";
        NSString *part = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i", divider, value & (1 << i) ? 1 : 0];
        [string insertString:part atIndex:0];
    }

    return string;
}

@end
```

**In use**

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString binaryStringRepresentationOfInt:0]);
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString binaryStringRepresentationOfInt:1]);
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString binaryStringRepresentationOfInt:2]);
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString binaryStringRepresentationOfInt:3]);
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString binaryStringRepresentationOfInt:7]);
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString binaryStringRepresentationOfInt:16]);
```

**Outputs**

```
0000 0000
0000 0001
0000 0010
0000 0011
0000 0111
0001 0000
```

Answer (score 1):

The string is printing the integers, because that's what you're putting into it (%i == integer). %c is the token for characters.

Or, you can just pass the array into `-[NSString initWithBytes:length:encoding:]`. If you a string with a single byte, use the same method, passing an offset pointer into the array, and a length of one.

Comment: Hi kperry
I have tried but i am not getting the byte value copied into NSString , any idea?

Comment: I'd have to see the code you used when you tried it to help you any more.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(NSString *)toBinary:(NSInteger)input
{
 if (input == 1 || input == 0) {
 return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8d", input];
 }
 else
 {
 NSString * myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", [self toBinary:input / 2], input %    2];
 NSRange stringRange = {[myString length] - 8,8};
 NSString *shortString = [myString substringWithRange:stringRange];
 return shortString;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code

```
NSString *str =  [ [NSString alloc] initWithBytes:barr length:sizeof(barr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

I have tried ASCII encoding also , but it gives empty string only.