# Is there any method in Objective-C which has the same functionality as "String(_ v: T, radix: Int, uppercase: Bool = default)" in Swift?

Tags: objective-c

I've just found a binary version [NSString to Print in in binary format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286425/nsstring-to-print-in-in-binary-format), but I want to know if there is a flexible version.

```
let initialBits: UInt8 = 0b00001111
let invertedBits = ~initialBits // equals 11110000
let stringOfInvertedBits = String(invertedBits, radix: 2) // convert to string in binary
print(stringOfInvertedBits) // 11110000
```

`radix: 2` means binary, and `radix: 8` means octonary, etc...

Comment: Can you explain exactly what functionality you want so we don't have to go and research that method ourselves?

Comment: Yes, I've changed the question.

Comment: What does flexible mean in this context? What do you mean "NSString to Print in binary format"? Print the string's bytes?

Comment: @NicolasMiari Sorry for my poor english, I want the `radix` parameter , `radix: 2` means binary, and `radix: 8` means octonary.

Comment: @NicolasMiari Not always convert int to NSString in binary format.

Comment: @NicolasMiari There is a UInt8 0b00001111, when I print the 0b00001111, I get `15` on the screen, but I want to print the `00001111`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a modification of @Paul Griffiths answer, which is faster and more efficient as it avoids constant re-allocation of the `NSString`:

```
- (NSString *)formatStringFromInt:(int)value withRadix:(int)radix
{
    if (value == 0)
        return @"0";
    if (radix < 2 || radix > 36)
        radix = 10;

    const unsigned buffsize = 64;
    unichar buffer[buffsize];
    unsigned offset = buffsize;
    static const char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    int absValue = abs(value);
    while (absValue > 0) {
        buffer[--offset] = (unichar)digits[absValue % radix];
        absValue /= radix;
    }

    if (value < 0)
        buffer[--offset] = '-';

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:buffer + offset
                                         length:buffsize - offset];
}
```

Produces:

```
2016-01-08 11:52:53.644 stringformatprefix[7560:606490] D
2016-01-08 11:52:53.645 stringformatprefix[7560:606490] 13
2016-01-08 11:52:53.645 stringformatprefix[7560:606490] -15
2016-01-08 11:52:53.645 stringformatprefix[7560:606490] -23
2016-01-08 11:52:53.645 stringformatprefix[7560:606490] 1101
```

Comment: It's good to avoid the constant reallocations, as you say, but this function will get the digits back to front. You'd need to calculate the last place and then write the digits to the string from end to beginning (or reverse the string at the end, before adding any `'-'` sign).

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Good catch!  How about now?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy modification:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSString * getBitStringForInt(const int value, const int radix) {
    static const char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    if ( radix < 2 || radix > 36 ) {
        return NULL;
    }

    NSString *bits = @"";
    int absValue = abs(value);

    while ( absValue ) {
        bits = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%@", digits[absValue % radix], bits];
        absValue /= radix;
    }

    if ( value < 0 ) {
        bits = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@", bits];
    }

    return bits;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString * val = getBitStringForInt(13, 16);
        NSLog(@"%@", val);

        val = getBitStringForInt(13, 10);
        NSLog(@"%@", val);

        val = getBitStringForInt(-13, 8);
        NSLog(@"%@", val);

        val = getBitStringForInt(-13, 5);
        NSLog(@"%@", val);

        val = getBitStringForInt(13, 2);
        NSLog(@"%@", val);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

with output:

```
2016-01-07 21:59:59.144 TestCmdLine[49904:18135090] D
2016-01-07 21:59:59.145 TestCmdLine[49904:18135090] 13
2016-01-07 21:59:59.145 TestCmdLine[49904:18135090] -15
2016-01-07 21:59:59.145 TestCmdLine[49904:18135090] -23
2016-01-07 21:59:59.145 TestCmdLine[49904:18135090] 1101
Program ended with exit code: 0
```